# Basic Spinner misbehavior

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

I have a simple layout (two `TextViews` and one `Spinner`), the array and the `MainActivity.java` which in the `onCreate` method, through an adapter populates the `Spinner`.

When I execute the app I can click on the `Spinner` but nothing happens in android 4.3(API level 16) and a empty, white row is displayed in android2.3.3(Api level 10).
Shouldn't I at least see and select one of the strings?

**main.xml**:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/question" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/question"
        android:text="@string/one" />

   <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/nationalities_spinner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/question"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
       android:entries="@array/nationalities_array"
       android:tag="@string/select_string" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The array for the `Spinner`:

```
<string-array name="nationalities_array">
    <item>Italian</item>
    <item>German</item>
    <item>British</item>
    <item>Dutch</item>
</string-array>
```

and the `MainActivity.java`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        Spinner nationalities_spinner  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nationalities_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.array.nationalities_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nationalities_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't see something in your `Spinner` because you use an incorrect constructor for the `ArrayAdapter` which results in an empty `ArrayAdapter` for your `Spinner`. You use [this `ArrayAdapter` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) and provide something different than what it wants(a layout file resource and an id of a `TextView` from that layout file). Instead you probably want this :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.nationalities_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works properly now. the difference is that I don't create an instance of ArrayAdapter but I use only the createfromResource method?

Comment: @Lucifero123 The `createFromResource` method creates a new `ArrayAdapter` instance from the array and the layout file that you supply. The constructor you used creates a new **empty** (no data in it) `ArrayAdapter` from the layout file and it will bind the data that you supply to the `ArrayAdapter` at a later time(for example with the `add` method) to a `TextView` from the row layout with the specified id.

Comment: @Lucifero123 I see that you are new on stackoverflow. If my answer helped you can choose to mark it as correct(with the check mark near the answer), this will give both of us some reputation points, it will mark the question as answered and it will help you in the future if you'll ask other questions.